# Database location in WordPress

Tags: database

I have created my website in WordPress and want to transfer it in my domain created with ipage. I am not able to locate the WordPress database. Can you help me? How is the format or extension of DB with WP. I have send to ipage all the files under XAMPP and WordPress but they still say DB is missing.

I need to know where the database is located in WP and what is the extension

Comment: you have your website on your localhost ?

Comment: if you want to migrate your wordpress.com blog to your own domain then you can follow these step http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-your-blog-from-wordpress-com-to-wordpress-org/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the database information by looking at your wp-config.php (which will be in your WordPress root folder).

Your wp-config.php will probably tell you then that your database host is "localhost" (DB_HOST) and since you are using XAMPP locally, the location of your DB would be wherever you are running MySQL basis your XAMPP installation.  XAMPP comes with phpMyAdmin for managing the DB.  That should help.

wp-config.php will also tell you the name of your database (DB_NAME).  The table prefix is found farther down where it says $table_prefix.

Comment: is "wp-config.php" file the **only** file that keeps info about database in wordpress? I want to have a two language website, But each lang must have its own database. because the host and domains are completely different, I want to copy all files in english site and past them in "other lang" site and just change database info. So it is important for me to know that "is "wp-config.php" file the **only** file that keeps info about database in wordpress?" or not?